# Print control as A4 format

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, pdfsharp

I'm using `Control.DrawToBitmap` in order to achieve an image snapshot of my winform part .

Successively, I get a pdf file by conversion that image object through free component (pdfsharp).

However, my final pdf doesn't fill the entire are of document, that's because it's not an A4 sheet format (in fact, whan I crate bitmap object I pass its constructor size of control that I want to print).

It could be interesting to create an image object typical of A4 format, but I have not idea how do it for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear to me.

When drawing images in PDFsharp, you can specify the position only to have the image drawn with the default size. I presume this is what the threadopener does.

You can specify the size using optional parameters of DrawImage - this way you can blow an icon (32x32 pixel) up to DIN A 4 size or more.

See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=5099#p5099

Comment: Ok, but pixel are related DPI on my machine, moreover I don't know how convert pixel size to "A4" size. For instance, which can be a pixel value typical of A4 size?

Comment: PDF files have no pixels (vector format). To leave 2 cm border around the image, you would call "gfx.DrawImage(img, XUnit.FromCentimeter(2), XUnit.FromCentimeter(2), XUnit.FromCentimeter(17), XUnit.FromCentimeter(25.7));" This can be improved to maintain the aspect ratio and draw centered.